# Login is skipped if user is logged in the backend

Tags: authentication, typo3, typo3-7.6.x

I currently have a behaviour that I can't explain with a frontend login. Everything works great until I am logged in the backend. At that point the frontend login becomes unusable.
It automatically redirects to the internal area.

Data dump:

```
$GLOBALS['TSFE']->fe_user->user

array(usergroup => '1')
```

Nothing else. 
Without the parallel backend session I can use the login and everything works. The data dump is the full and correct frontend user.

Using the logout button amounts to nothing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am just guessing and there are several options: Either you are using an extensions which fakes a login or you are using the admin panel which can emulate a logged in usergroup. If it is the latter, you can e.g. clear the user cache (backend > user settings > clear cache) or open the admin panel and remove the setting.

Comment: admPanel.override.preview.simulateUserGroup = 0
Solved my problems. Thanks.